# Swift: Replace String array at index

Tags: swift

I have the following String Array:

```
var stringArray:[String] = ["value1", "value2", "value3", "value4"]
```

how can I replace for example the third String with index 2 ("value 3") with another string?

Answer (score 326, accepted):

Simple as that:

```
stringArray[2] = "new string"
```

Comment: Thank you. Sometimes, it's easy to forget the little things, and you end up googling for "replace array element"!

Comment: @Womble I guess that's the swift style that made us forgets that. I am pretty sure no-one can forgets that how its done in C++

Comment: I am sure that I have searched for the answer multiple times and always reach here 

Comment: Another visit to the same page!

Comment: @ManeeshM You should go on vacation

Comment: Just make sure to check that `stringArray.count` is less than the index you're attempting to replace the element at!

Comment: @cohen72 the index needs to be lower than the arrays count

Comment: @Adam oy vey, I had it backwards ... :)

Comment: Swift evolves extremely fast, so, it's always better to check the latest online response before doing something after a while!

Comment: And here I am again, over 4 years since I left my comment about how easy it is to forget, still googling for the same answer...